# onClick in Map func,only execute for one element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Is there any method for map function to only execute Dropdown menu for one cart.For now if i click on one Menu icon , every dropdown appears for every Card in map.

```
 const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  {albums.map((album, i) => (
        <Card width="23rem" height="16rem" bckImg={album.bckImgUrl} key={i}>
          <AlbumtTitle color={album.color}>{album.name}</AlbumtTitle>
          <LinkButton background={album.color} to={`/albums/${album._id}`}>
            See more
          </LinkButton>
          <KebabMenu onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} open={isOpen}>
            {isOpen ? (
              <Dropdown
                ref={ref}
                style={{
                  width: "50px",
                  height: "50px",
                }}
              >
                <li>
                  <Link to={`editAlbum/${album._id}`}>Edit</Link>
                </li>
                <hr />
                <li>Delete</li>
              </Dropdown>
            ) : (
              <Dots />
            )}
          </KebabMenu>
        </Card>
      ))}
```

Comment: You should store the `isOpen` state for each dropdown separately. Currently one `isOpen` state controls all the dropdowns at once.

Comment: How to do store it separately  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `isOpen` state can be an object that tracks the open state per item in the album:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState({});

{albums.map((album, i) => (
    <Card width="23rem" height="16rem" bckImg={album.bckImgUrl} key={i}>
      <AlbumtTitle color={album.color}>{album.name}</AlbumtTitle>
      <LinkButton background={album.color} to={`/albums/${album._id}`}>
        See more
      </LinkButton>
      <KebabMenu
        onClick={() =>
          setIsOpen({ ...isOpen, [album._id]: !isOpen[album._id] })
        }
        open={!!isOpen[album._id]}
      >
        {isOpen[album._id] ? (
          <Dropdown
            ref={ref}
            style={{
              width: "50px",
              height: "50px",
            }}
          >
            <li>
              <Link to={`editAlbum/${album._id}`}>Edit</Link>
            </li>
            <hr />
            <li>Delete</li>
          </Dropdown>
        ) : (
          <Dots />
        )}
      </KebabMenu>
    </Card>
  ))}
```

Comment: Is it good i change your const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState({}); to  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);. I did it because it set state on second click first doesnt done noting.

Comment: That won't work; it has to be an object because there needs to be a boolean value for each album_id

Comment: @KubaKluzniak it will work and ignore the default value, but it;s not good practice, just put the {} instead of boolean as the start value

Comment: Ok. i Chage it for this: useState({ id: undefined, state: false }); setIsOpen({ [album._id]: !isOpen[album._id] })} and its working fine

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to default the state like this. That's still not representative of what it'll look like. The state will end up looking like `{1: true, 2: false, 3: false}` etc. (assuming the album IDs are 1, 2, and 3)

Comment: @Nick because at first click at dropdown when sate is empty object at first nothing happends , it start to work at second click .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```js
 {albums.map((album, i) => (...your code...))}
```

you need to check whether you have at least one item in albums, and if yes, process it:

```js
{if (albums.length > 0) {
   return albums.slice(0,1).map((album, i) => (...your code...))
 } else {
   return null // or any other actions you want to take in case there are no albums
 }
}
```

To clarify, we check the length of the albums, if it is not empty. If it is, we take only the first element and process it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion i will add this.

Comment: @kuba-kluzniak, please upvote my answer if it helped you :)